# How to account for time in linear mixed effects model?

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model

I have data collected over a year  in months Oct2021, Dec2021, Jan2022, April2022, July2022, Aug2022, Oct2022. Ultimately, I would like to understand how my response variable varies across time. I know I could consider time in two ways, either considering the seven months ( counting each October as a unique one), or considering seasons Autumn1, Winter, Spring, Summer, Autumn2.

I have different covariates to factor in  (cov1, cov2, cov3, cov4, cov5) to this linear mixed effects model. I was going to have subject ID as a random effect. And as a fixed effect either time represented in months or seasons. Time in either format would not be a random effect here? Just wanted to double check.

Thank you

Comment: That depends on whether you want to have random slopes or not.

Comment: If time were measured continuously in days (highly preferred) you could easily simultaneously model both long-term and seasonal trends as exemplified [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg.html#sec-genreg-gtrans).  But it is [usually a mistake](https://fharrell.com/post/re)  to handle within-subject correlation only through random effects.  Serial correlation methods are better and don't make as many approximations as mixed models.